# Why does the callback function called at the end and how to test the function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following function which is invoked on the button click which in turn calls an another function inside the timer.

Here is the code:

```
<button id="starter">Start</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById ("starter").addEventListener ("click", myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("Start", start);
  d3.timer(() => {
    var timepassed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    console.log("Time elapsed", timepassed);
    helloBlah(timepassed);
    if(timepassed >= 200) return true;
  });
  console.log(" Why am I triggered first rather than the timer?");
}

function helloBlah(e){
  console.log("Hello Blah");
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seh4p76h/7/).

Why does the d3 timer and the function inside are invoked later than the console message below it? How can I make it invoke before the console message and how do I write a test in Jasmine for these kind of functions?

Comment: The timer is asynchronous and JavaScript is single-threaded. This means the callback won't be called until the time is up and the currently running thread is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour.

D3 timers are different from `setTimeout` and `setInterval`: among other things, they stop when the page is backgrounded.

However, just like what happens when you use a `setTimeout` with 0 ms, the behaviour you see is explained by the fact that setting the *minimum delay* doesn't mean that the function will be executed *immediately*: it just means that it will be executed right after the currently executing code is finished.

We can show this using `d3.timeout` (not present in v3, only v4), which unlike `d3.timer` is called only once. Have a look at the console:

```js
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  d3.timeout(function() {
    console.log("I'm inside d3.timeout, I should come first!")
  });
  console.log("I'm outside d3.timeout and after it")
  console.log("I'm outside d3.timeout and after it too")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Regarding the other two questions, please keep just **one problem** per post. Asking more than one question per post is a reason to close here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Will keep that in mind :) The explanation helped a lot. Cheers.